# Organise array push order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an array. I push items multiple times into this array using a function. Below is an simplified version of the code.

```
var arr = [];

function pushItems(i){
  //do something with i
  var abc = "string"
  arr.push(abc);

  //do something with i
  var xyz = "string"
  arr.push(xyz);
}
```

Sometimes `abc` value is pushed before `xyz`. Sometimes `xyz` gets pushed before `abc` value. My question is how do I always have the `abc` value ahead of 'xyz' value?

So basically I need the array values to be `[abc1, xyz1, abc2, xyz2, abc3, xyz3, ...]` so on. How do I order the push accordingly?

Comment: Why don't you sort the array after your push?

Comment: Your observation is wrong or your posted code isn't relevant (what about `i`???). `push()` will always work the same

Comment: @pwee167 thanks. sort by what?

Comment: It's plain impossible that, with the code given, xyz is added before abc is. If you are pushing items separately in event handlers or async requests it can happen, and in that case you'll have to either sort your array or assign the position in the array specifically (`arr[0] = abc`) instead of using `.push`

Comment: I'm not sure what criteria you want to sort by, but the push method in an array appends the item to the end of the list. So if you want ordering of some sort, you will need to sort it.

Comment: @A.Wolff: thanks for your comment. My problem is that the push is not consistent. Therefore an xyz value gets pushed before an abc value or sometime the other way around. I need to make sure a xyz gets pushed after an abc value

Comment: @Becky push() **is consistent**, your issue comes from some part of your code you didn't posted. You have anyway to post minimalistic sample replicating your issue

Comment: @pwee167: I'm afraid that the sort will not work for me. The array contains base64 strings.

Comment: Hi. Can you use two arrays, one for XYZ and the other for ABC the merge them in the order you need?

Comment: @A.Wolff: May be I should have told that the push items are base64 encoded urls. So the push time depends on the size of the image. So at times xyz completes ahead of abc - so the order is not right.

Comment: @Becky So this has nothing to do with `push()` but regarding async operations, images onload event i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff. yes. but if I can push them in the order I need, that would solve my issues. That's what I was trying.

Comment: Well the code you posted does not replicate the issue you are having, so the question is impossible to answer. If you doing the .push in a callback for an async request (like .onload), that changes everything. Please post a snippet with more detail.

Comment: @Becky So push base64string at time you are requesting it, not once loaded or whatever, actually, your logic is wrong. But as you didn't have posted any relevant code, we cannot help you more

Comment: @Becky what is the requirement for your sorting? You are pushing base64 strings, so it isn't alphabetical - but how do you define what needs to be in front of what? If this is a completely arbitrary order, then set `arr[0] = "base64stringofABC"` and `arr[1] = "base64stringofXYZ"` instead of using `.push`.

Comment: @WardD.S. That's a good suggestion. thanks :) but that `arr[0]` , `arr[1]` wouldn't work as I'm passing multiple urls into `pushItems(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need your base64-strings to be in an arbitrary order in the array, sort them by an identifier you define.

```
var firstObj = {id: 0, base64: 'asdf'}
var secondObj = {id: 1, base64: 'qwer'}
var arr = []
// do stuff

// callback needs to have something along these lines:
function base64isLoaded(obj){
  arr[obj.id] = obj.base64;
}
```

Now the 'front' image (as you gave this as example) can be given id: 0, so it ends up in the '0' spot of the array. I can't really help more without more information about how your code is structured.

**EDIT**: From your comment ("passing multiple items into pushItems"), I am going to assume that `i` (the argument) is an array and you iterate this array to transform each element into a base64 encoded string. You then want these encoded strings added to `arr` **in the same order**, correct?

easily done, simply make `i` an array of objects:

```
var i = [{source: 'abc'}, {source: 'xyz'}];
pushItems(i){
  for(var c = 0; c < i.length; c++){
    makeIntoBase64(i[c]);
  }
}

makeIntoBase64(obj){
  // this is whatever function that transforms it and takes a callback when it is done
  transform(obj.source, function(result){ //pass the source to be encoded
    //result should be base64 encoded string
    obj.encoded = result;
  });
}
```

after all this, the array `i` has objects with both `.source` and `.encoded`. If you need to know when ALL encoding is done, create a counter and add one to it in the transform callback, and check if `counter === i.length` every time. When it is, you know you have loaded all base64 strings and can run another function, adding these images to your catalogue or whatever else you need this for :)

Comment: @Becky added something for you. see if that helps you :)

Answer (score 8):

This is wrong. According to the specification of this method:

> The push() method adds one or more elements **to the end** of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

Please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

For a more formal approach please see the ECMAScript specification [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7).

> The arguments are appended to the end of the array, in the order in
>   which they appear. The new length of the array is returned as the
>   result of the call.

**Update**

> But even if the elements are added at the end of the array, I'm
>   looking a way of ordering my array.

You can use the `sort` function for this reason passing to it an appropriate function that will do the compare. For instance, let we have the following array

```
var array = [4,1,2,5,3];
```

and we want to order it in a descending order, we could do this like below:

```
var array = array.sort(function(a,b){ return b-a; });
```

Comment: thanks. That's a good point. But even if the elements are added at the end of the array, I'm looking a way of ordering my array.

Comment: @Becky you are welcome dude. I am glad that I helped. For that you want you can use the `sort` function. Give me a few minutes and I will update my answer.

Comment: Sort will not work coz the array contains base64 urls

Comment: @Becky if you are pushing `base64 encoded urls` to array, i don't see any purpose of sorting it... You seems to want to get array in order you requested images, is it?

Comment: @A.Wolff just imagine you're showing images for a catelogue. The item is a chair. The order is used to show the front and rear view of the item. Hope that makes scenes.

Comment: @Becky It could make sense  but it is too broad to be answered. **We** need to see concrete sample regarding your logic. And it sounds like you'd have better to use an object, not an array: `var myChair = {front:"url1", back: "url2", etc...}`